# Find $\lim\limits_{x \to 0+} \theta (x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to 0-} \theta (x)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have went through the Lagrange theorem ($f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)(b-a)$), and now looking at the following problem:

Prove that for positive $x$, the following is true:

$$\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+\theta (x)}}$$
where $1/4 < \theta(x) < 1/2$. Find $\lim\limits_{x \to 0+} \theta (x)$ and $\lim\limits_{x \to 0-} \theta (x)$.

Struggling with this. I can see that $f(b)-f(a)=x+1-x=1$, which means that $f'(c) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x+\theta(x)}}$, but this does not help me much. No integration should be used in this solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use Lagrange's theorem. You can simply use the given relation and solve for $\theta(x)$.

$$
\theta (x) = \frac 14 \left(1+ 2 \sqrt{x^2+x}-2x\right)
$$

The given bounds and the value of the right limit come directly from this expression. The left limit does not make sense as the expression in not defined for negative $x$.

In fact, $\theta$ is an increasing function of $x$ defined for $x \ge 0$ and you have that
$$
\lim_{x \to 0^+} \theta(x)= \frac 14
$$

and

$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty} \theta (x) = \frac 12.
$$

Answer (score 0):

As a check:

$f(x+1)-f(x)= f'(t)$, where $x <t_x<x+1$.

With $f(x)=√x$ , $x >0$ .

$\sqrt{x+1}-√x = (1/2)(t_x)^{-1/2}$, $x <t_x <x+1$.

Comparing with the expression given:

$t_x = x+\theta(x)$, we have

$x < x +\theta(x) <x+1$,

$0< \theta(x) <1$, $x >0$.

Limits $x \rightarrow 0^+$, and $x \rightarrow \infty.$

Solve for $\theta (x),$ as done by PierreCarree.

$\theta (x) =(1/4)(1+2(\sqrt{x^2+x}-2x).$

1)$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+}\theta (x)=1/4$.

2)$\theta (x)= (1/4)(1+2(\sqrt{x^2-x}-x);$

Recall: $(x^2+x) -x^2=$

$(\sqrt{x^2+x}+ x)(\sqrt{x^2+x}- x);$

$\sqrt{x^2+x}-x =\dfrac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+x}+x}=$

$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1+1/x}+1}.$

Finally:

$\lim_{ x\rightarrow \infty} \theta (x)= 1/2.$